# Finding imaginary part of a function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For this question it is assumed that $f(x+iy)$ is differentiable on $C$.

For a function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, the real part $u(x,y)=(e^{-x})Cos(y)+xy$.

Now, I am trying to find the imaginary part of the function and used the Cauchy-Riemann equation and got the following.

Firstly I used the Cauchy Riemann equation and got

$$Du/Dx=(-e^{-x})\cos y+y.$$

Then for $$Du/Dy=(e^{-x})\cdot(-\sin y)+x$$

What is the next step or is that complete?

Answer attempt

$ V = ∫ ((-e^{-x})cosy + y )dy $

This obtains $ (-e^{-x})siny +1/2y^2 + ϕ(x) $

$ Dv/Dx = (e^{-x})(-siny)+ ϕ′(x) $

Thus we have

$(-e^{-x})siny + 1/2y^2 + 1/2x^2 + C$

Is that correct?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You've just copied & pasted that without trying anything, haven't you? Please tell us what you've tried by editing the question.

Comment: @shaun Is that along the right lines?

Comment: In the next step you use the CR equations $Du/Dx=Dv/Dy$ and $Du/Dy=-Dv/Dx$ and try to integrate $v$.

Comment: So I've completed that and got the following:

Comment: would the above be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivative $\frac{∂v}{∂x}$ is wrong, you are somehow moving minus signs around without needing to and getting it wrong.

$$
v(x,y)=−e^{−x}\sin y+\frac12y^2+ϕ(x)\\
\implies
\frac{∂v}{∂x}=e^{-x}\sin y+ϕ'(x)
$$
and comparing with
$$
-\frac{∂u}{∂y}=e^{−x}\sin y-x
$$
gives $ϕ'(x)=-x$, $ϕ(x)=-\frac12x^2+C$ so that in total
$$
f(z)=e^{-z}-\frac{i}2z^2+iC
$$
which is indeed an entire holomorphic function.